# Crear una gráfica con matplotlib en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

no consigo hacer que el siguiente código realice solo una gráfica, donde los valores sean (x,y), en vez de 2 gráficas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def representar_xxx_yyy(datos,titulos = ['', '', '']):
    plt.plot(datos)
    plt.title(titulos[0])
    plt.ylabel(titulos[1])
    plt.xlabel(titulos[2])
    plt.show()
    

representar_xxx_yyy([(1, 8), (2, 4), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.25)], ["Rótulo principal", "Ordenadas", "Abcisas"])
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html), la forma de entregar los pares de valores es en dos arrays separados, `x` e `y`. En tu caso:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def representar_xxx_yyy(datosx, datosy, titulos = ['', '', '']):
    plt.plot(datosx, datosy)
    plt.title(titulos[0])
    plt.ylabel(titulos[1])
    plt.xlabel(titulos[2])
    plt.show()
    

representar_xxx_yyy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25], ["Rótulo principal", "Ordenadas", "Abcisas"])
```